# chmod: changing permissions of file system

Tags: 18.04, permissions, vmware, chmod, tar

I'm having problems to execute file in my VMware folder, I tried changing permissions, but it does not change but give this error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of <filename> Read-only file system
```

I tried using `chmod +x`, `chmod 777` and several others.

Still not able to run the file.

Please see image [image: file permissions]

**Note by Yaron**: During the discussion in chat we understood that the read-only file system is a CD mounted to the VM.

Comment: which file do you fail to execute?

Comment: run_upgrade.sh, I see it is set to permission -r--r--r--

Comment: in the attached photo, we can see that `run_upgrade` has `-r-xr-xr-x` permissions. i.e. it is executable

Comment: Do you run your commands as user `root` or as `oxidized` ?

Comment: sorry, it's true. It's the tar.gz file that won't extract

Comment: If you like to extact `.tag.gz` file you should use the `tar xf filename.tar.gz` command

Comment: yes. I have done that. But I'm getting errors such as this " tar: vmware-tools-distrib/etc/installer.sh: Cannot open: no such file or directory" and " cannot mkdir: Read-only file system"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88242/discussion-between-yaron-and-user3768971).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you tried to write to a `CD` which is a read-only system.

You should first copy the file to a write-able folder (e.g. another folder in your VM which is located on HDD).

Afterwards if you want to extract `filename.tar.gz` file You can extract it using:

```
tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
```

or by using:

```
tar xf filename.tar.gz
```